# sudo apt install not working for anything

Tags: apt

I installed Ubuntu 18.04(LTS) just yesterday. I am trying to install packages using **sudo apt-get install** , but I am getting the below error (this example is for 'make') :

**Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate**

I tried googling it, found something related to mirrors and sources, but not able to figure out what to do. Please help.

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` without errors?

Comment: @Parto the command that you gave worked. It updated everything. After that I was able to install whatever I wanted.

Comment: Awesome. Look online for "Top things to do after installing Ubuntu 18.04"

Answer (score 1):

whenever you install fresh ubuntu always run

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`

*please google what each command does for more info :)*

only then must you find the packages you are looking for and install. Happens to me all the time.

Comment: You could add a short note on what each command does for readers' reference?